# Why do I get unexpected token: 'setYear' from this method

Tags: apex

Why do I get unexpected token: 'setYear' from this method

```
public Integer PageReference setYear()
{
    return yearChosen = 2017;

}
```

Comment: you have two return types for a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two return types. It should be like this:

```
public Integer setYear()
{
    return yearChosen = 2017;

}
```